# Webpage error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Can anyone help me with the below error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 5 Nov 2010 15:43:56 UTC

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.iol.co.za/

Comment: What code is causing the problem? And what is the problem? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag makes reference to a move() function which does not exist, because of a mis-configured JavaScript.

> body
>   onload="MM_preloadImages('/images/multimedia_gal_prev2.jpg','/images/multimedia_gal_next2.jpg','/images/multimedia_gal_forward2.gif','/images/multimedia_gal_back2.gif','/images/a_tool_email_2.jpg','/images/a_tool_print_2.jpg','/images/pagination_prev_hov.jpg','/images/pagination_next_hov.jpg');
>   timer=setTimeout('**move()**',1000)">

Try removing the text that reads:

"Script courtesy of http://www.web-source.net - Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development"

Make sure you leave the 'var = nullfunction move()' intact after that bit of text.